# make Chrome extension contextMenu load

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm working on a chrome extension and it's a contextMenu and appears in the right click menu . but the problem is , you have to open the extension from the up-right corner of chrome to make it appear in the right click menu. my javascripts are external . 
here's my javascript codes :

```
window.onload = myOnload;
function myOnload(){
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.onclick= function(){myClick()};
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
      "title":"MissLang Fix",
      "contexts":["all"]
  });
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "mojtaba";
}


function myClick(){
    var myString = document.getElementById("input").value;

    for(var i=0;i<myString.length;i++){
        myString = myString.replace("q","ض");
        myString = myString.replace("w","ص");
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

and here's my manifest.json codes :

```
{
    "name": "MissLang Fix extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "fixing english to farsi typings.",
    "icons":{
        "16":"icon_16.png",
        "128":"icon_128.png"
    },

    "browser_action":   {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "missLangFix.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "contextMenus",
    ]

}
```

I wanted to know where should I put my chrome.contextMenus.create code to make the icon appear in the right click menu even before user opens the extension from the right side of address bar . 
thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html).

`manifest.json`

```
...
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
...
```

Put your script inside `background.js` so that it would run as the user opens up the browser.

#### Extra (related)

You can also make your extension runs as the user log in to Windows/Apple/linux by:

```
"permissions": [
    "background"
]
```

Comment: Thanks Derek , I tried them both but still I doesn't show the icon in the right click without first opening the extension on the right side of the address bar .

Comment: I added these two lines to my manifest.json : "background":{"scripts":["script.js"]}, and the other line in the permissions : "background" but it still doesn't work

Comment: The background permission is not needed, because all logic is only meaningful when the browser's UI is visible. Use the background permission when the extension is also useful when there's no browser, for instance an alarm+notification extension.

Comment: Thanks , it works now , there was two lines before chrome.contextMenus.create which was like this : var button = document.getElementById("button"); button.onclick = function(){myClick()}; I put these two lines after chrome.contextMenus.creat and now it works . I wonder why these two lines were preventing the loading of the script

Comment: @smtabatabaie - Chrome might think `.onclick` is inline script and therefore it will throw an error. Or it might just because the button `#button` does not exist.